# Selecting columns with numeric values including null

Tags: python, pandas

I want to select columns with numeric values including null

Using this code

```
numeric_cols=set(dfAcepCtrUsers.select_dtypes(include=[np.number]).columns.values)
```

It will exclude columns with null values like

```
col
===
1
2
None
```

What's the correct way of selecting numeric columns including columns like these?

Answer (score 0):

You can first *attempt* to convert all columns in your DataFrame to numeric type with

```
df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='ignore'))
```

while non-digit columns will be left alone.

Then, your column including `None` will no longer be of dtype `object`, and shall be captured with `select_dtypes`.

**Demo**

```
>>> df
  nulls strings
0     3     foo
1     2     bar
2  None     baz

>>> set(df.select_dtypes(include=[np.number]))
set()

>>> df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='ignore'))

>>> df 
   nulls strings
0    3.0     foo
1    2.0     bar
2    NaN     baz

>>> set(df.select_dtypes(include=[np.number]))
{'nulls'}
```